# Captured photo with stripes

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I'm using [MediaCapture class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.media.capture.mediacapture.aspx) to take a photo with Windows Phone 8.1 Runtime. The code, where I take a picture looks like this:

```
// create a file
StorageFile photoFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("myFirstPhoto.jpg", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

// take a photo with choosen Encoding
await captureManager.CapturePhotoToStorageFileAsync(ImageEncodingProperties.CreateJpeg(), photoFile);
```

The code is working quite fine, as I get a picture, but with strange stripes on left and right side:

[image]

I'm trying to find a solution for this problem, but without success. Am I missing something?

EDIT - Photos takes from build-in app are without stripes, so this seems not to be a problem with hardware.

Comment: Hi, Romasz. I got you have vast knowledge about windows phone. I'm stuck in my application.    problem is,,  for creating a profile,  I get a file from user with fileopenpicker and convert that select image into bytes and save that bytes in SQLite data base...  when I get the the data of all profile then I'm not able to convert my image bytes to image in list. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32748330/listbox-image-control-binding-with-sqlite-image-bytes-are-stored-in-database-c

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok I've figured it out myself - it's a problem with resolution which is set as default when using `MediaCapture`. If you set maximum resolution just after Initializing `MediaCapture` then there will be no stripes:

```
// just after initialization
var maxResolution = captureManager.VideoDeviceController.GetAvailableMediaStreamProperties(MediaStreamType.Photo).Aggregate(
                    (i1, i2) => (i1 as VideoEncodingProperties).Width > (i2 as VideoEncodingProperties).Width ? i1 : i2);
await captureManager.VideoDeviceController.SetMediaStreamPropertiesAsync(MediaStreamType.Photo, maxResolution);
```

Comment: This generates a `NullReferenceException` in my case, because the the returned IEnumerable contains two `PhotoEncodingProperties`, where the casting returns null. This works for me: `var maxResolution = takePhotoManager.VideoDeviceController.GetAvailableMediaStreamProperties(MediaStreamType.Photo).Aggregate(
                (i1, i2) => (i1 is VideoEncodingProperties ? (i1 as VideoEncodingProperties).Width : 0) > (i2 is VideoEncodingProperties ? (i2 as VideoEncodingProperties).Width : 0) ? i1 : i2);`

Comment: @CedricReichenbach I haven't encountered such a problem, but to be honest I've tested this on one device = so thanks for the comment and the code. Note also that the maximum width may not mean the maximum resolution, so depending on your case you may use different method to choose the best resolution - just a remark.

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me, but I had to set it for both, MediaStreamType.Photo and MediaStreamType.VideoPreview!

Comment: @MahnikLassdas Have you used this only to take photos or also to record video? I haven't tried this for some time, thaks for the tip.

Comment: I show a camera preview stream with a shutter button to take a picture.

Comment: For posterity: The reason the stripes appeared is due to a mismatch between the preview aspect ratio and the capture aspect ratio. These need to match, or artifacts like these might appear.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with the lowest resolution it gets the same stripes.
From MS Advance Camera sample, they use MediaCapture for preview but SilverLight API for capturing!

The MediaCapture has also memory leak issue each time when you call CapturePhotoToXXX API.

I wonder if they already know MediaCapture is badly managed on WindowsPhone 8.1 and this is the reason why they don't provide a Camera MediaCapture sample with RT APIs.