# Poor Image Quality when capturing Photo on Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: camera, winjs, windows-phone-8.1

I am using MediaCapture.capturePhotoToStorageFileAsync in WinJS to capture photos on a Windows Phone 8.1 device (Lumia 625). The quality of the resulting image is always rather poor and far behind what the built-in camera app delivers.

So far I'm pretty much at a loss in regards to what to tweak and what nobs to turn. Does anybody have experience with this?

Update: It seems the issue is related to the camera not focusing properly. Why that is and how to resolve it is still another question.

Comment: Have you tried to change the resolution of device? [Here is in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23712387/2681948), but maybe will help.

Comment: Yes, tried that but it didn't improve the situation.