# Rotate image before saving in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, rotation, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

My app should save an image from camera. I wrote the code below:

1. Method which initializes the camera.

   ```
   Windows.Media.Capture.MediaCapture takePhotoManager;
   public async void InitializeCamera()
   {
       takePhotoManager = new Windows.Media.Capture.MediaCapture();

       await takePhotoManager.InitializeAsync();
       takePhotoManager.SetPreviewRotation(VideoRotation.Clockwise90Degrees);
       PhotoPreview.Source = takePhotoManager;
       await takePhotoManager.StartPreviewAsync();
       // to stop it
       //await takePhotoManager.StopPreviewAsync();
   }
   ```
2. Method which saves a photo:

   ```
   public async void SavePhoto()
   {
       ImageEncodingProperties imgFormat = ImageEncodingProperties.CreateJpeg();

       var file = await KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.CreateFileAsync("Photo.jpg", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

       await takePhotoManager.CapturePhotoToStorageFileAsync(imgFormat, file);
   }
   ```
3. Preview

   ```
       <CaptureElement x:Name="PhotoPreview" FlowDirection="LeftToRight"
           HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
           VerticalAlignment="Center" 
           Stretch="UniformToFill">
       </CaptureElement>
   ```

I have two problems: 
1. The preview does not fill the entire space
[image]

2. After saving I get something like this: (without rotation and with transparent layers on both sides).
   [image]

Thanks

Comment: Maybe answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23709547/2681948) will help. You may also find some information [here at this post](http://www.romasz.net/how-to-take-a-photo-in-windows-runtime/).

Comment: Thanks, it resolve my issue connected with transparent spaces. Unfortunately, I still have problem with rotate image after saving proces, and fill all space in preview.

Comment: Have you tried with: `HorizontalAlignment="Strech" VerticalAlignment="Strech"` of *CaptureElement* in XAML?

Comment: Unfortunately it nothing changed.

Comment: Did you solve the rotation issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem may be in the panel you are using. As I can't see *Grid.Row* property in your *CaptureElement* in XAML then I suspect that you are using *StackPanel* - it's a panel that won't stretch to your screen it just stacks elements.

The thing you are trying to do should be possible with *Grid*, as I've checked the following code should work:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="0">
        <Button Click="InitCameraBtn_Click" Content="Initialize Camera" />
        <Button Click="StartPreviewBtn_Click" Content="Start Capture Preview" />
        <Button Click="StopPreviewBtn_Click" Content="Stop Capture Preview" />
    </StackPanel>

    <CaptureElement x:Name="PhotoPreview" Stretch="UniformToFill" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks Romasz. Yes, I used StackPanel. Your solution is right, but if you can see in the link [link](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=82A66D196A4DA30D!24008&authkey=!AB4fTSr-P-scBSw&v=3&ithint=photo%2cjpg) there are still black spaces near image from camera.

Comment: @user3149172 It's probaby because when you initialize, you choose the resolution wich has the biggest width (on my phone its 3552x2000). In fact there are other resolutions and for example 3264x2448 may be more suitable. Run in debug mode: `var resols = captureManager.VideoDeviceController.GetAvailableMediaStreamProperties(MediaStreamType.Photo).ToList();` and see what resolutions you have. You may also think about changing the code `var maxResolution = captureManager.VideoDeviceController.GetAvailableMedi...` for your purposes.

Comment: I think that is caused by my view. My maxResolution is OK, but if I add some controls above and below CaptureElement, it's scaled and I have black spaces on the left and on the right of image. But I don't know how resolve the problem...

Answer (score -1):

I can help with the first issue - changing the preview orientation. It looks like we have to manually change it on orientation change event.
The code is in Javascript. C# should be similar:

```
capture = new CaptureNS.MediaCapture();
//additional capture settings and init

function onOrientationChanged(e) {
    var o = e.orientation;
    //portrait
    if (o == 0 ) {
        capture && capture.setPreviewRotation(Windows.Media.Capture.VideoRotation.clockwise90Degrees);
    //landscape
    } else if (o == 1) {
        capture && capture.setPreviewRotation(Windows.Media.Capture.VideoRotation.none);
    } else if (o == 2) {
        capture && capture.setPreviewRotation(Windows.Media.Capture.VideoRotation.clockwise270Degrees);
    } else if (o == 3) {
        capture && capture.setPreviewRotation(Windows.Media.Capture.VideoRotation.clockwise180Degrees);
    } 
}

orientationSensor = Windows.Devices.Sensors.SimpleOrientationSensor.getDefault();
if (orientationSensor) {
    orientationSensor.onorientationchanged = onOrientationChanged;    
}
```

I didn't find any simple way to change orientation of the saved file.