# Listbox image control binding with SQLite , Image bytes are stored in Database C#

Tags: c#, sqlite, listbox, windows-phone-8.1

I have stored image bytes in SQLite database . when I want to get single image then I got that by id and convert image bytes to bitmap image. But when i want to bind list of data to listBox then I'm not able to bind directly  image control to bytes.

My Xaml code is here.

```
  <ListBox Background="Transparent" Margin="-5,2,-5,10" BorderThickness="0" MaxHeight="680" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="listBoxobj" SelectionChanged="listBoxobj_SelectionChanged">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
         <Grid Width="400" Margin="0,-10,0,0" >
           <Grid x:Name="pro_work_grid" Width="400" Height="120" Margin="0,0,0,0"
              VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="#31b1b0">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


     //Image will give here image bytes. not the source.  
     // Not know how to bind this with list,,which contain image bytes

     <Image x:Name="work_pic" Source="{Binding image}" Width="120" Height="120"
       Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0"
       Grid.ColumnSpan="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>

      <TextBlock x:Name="pro_name1" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="130,10,0,0"
       Text="{Binding  category}" FontSize="26" FontWeight="Bold">
       </TextBlock>

       <TextBlock x:Name="pro_title1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="130,10,0,0"
        Text="{Binding title}" FontSize="20" Foreground="White">

        </TextBlock>

                        </Grid>

                    </Grid>

                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

I have bind text block to directly by category,and title.. which are coming in List.

when my ListBox page loads then code work,,

```
  private void ReadContactList_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ReadAllContactsList dbcontacts = new ReadAllContactsList();
        DB_ContactList = dbcontacts.GetAllContacts();//Get all DB contacts 
        if (DB_ContactList.Count > 0)
        {   
        }                    
  listBoxobj.ItemsSource = DB_ContactList.OrderByDescending(i => i.Id).ToList();
    }
```

I'm able to get image from single image bytes. but here is the list of images display,,, so how can I get bytes and convert them into image control and show them separately in image control. 
Here is my Listbox items

[image]

Would you please help me?? I don't know the proper Syntax,,,Thanks in Advance

I convert image to bytes in this way.

```
   if (args != null)
        {
            if (args.Files.Count == 0) return;

            view.Activated -= viewActivated;
            StorageFile storageFile = args.Files[0];
            string pro_img_path = storageFile.Path;
            var stream = await storageFile.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
            filebite = new byte[stream.Size];
            using (DataReader reader = new DataReader(stream))
            {
                await reader.LoadAsync((uint)stream.Size);
                reader.ReadBytes(filebite);
            }
```

Again to reconvert these bytes to bitmap image.

```
   using (InMemoryRandomAccessStream ms = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
        {

            using (DataWriter writer = new DataWriter(ms.GetOutputStreamAt(0)))
            {
                writer.WriteBytes((byte[])pro_pic_byts);
                writer.StoreAsync().GetResults();
            }


            var img1 = new BitmapImage();
            img1.SetSource(ms);// = ms;
            pro_pic.Source = img1;
        }
```

Comment: Isn't `image` a property in the contact object (which also has the `category` and `title` properties)?

Comment: public byte[] image { get; set; }   Image is stored in bytes...   yes this is the property .. I got bytes rather than image or path from Database

Comment: And the byte array is an encoded image buffer, e.g. a JPEG or PNG? Than the binding should work without any converter.

Comment: I have to convert bytes to bitmap image,,, But just for single single image not the list of image....

Comment: I was talking about WPF, as you've tagged your question so. I've removed the tag. You need a binding converter, as shown in the answer.

Comment: Have you tried to use a converter to make BitmapImage form your stream and then set it as source? I think it may also be worth to take a look at BitmapEncoder/Decoder, some [help and guide at this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25994558/2681948).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you stored the image bytes, this may work :

```
public class BinaryToImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null) return null;

        if (value is IEnumerable<byte>)
        {
            List<byte> imgData = new List<byte>((IEnumerable<byte>)value);
            BitmapImage rval = new BitmapImage();

            rval.SetSource(new System.IO.MemoryStream(imgData.ToArray()));
            return rval;
        }
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Use this converter when binding your ImageSource to your `byte[]`

Comment: My xaml Image control source would be like this....    Source="{Binding IdentifierIcon,Converter={StaticResource byteToImageConverter}}"

Comment: Here, it would be simpler to cast `value` directly to `byte[]` and pass that to the MemoryStream constructor. That would save the intermediate `List<byte>`.

Comment: rval.SetSource(new System.IO.MemoryStream(imgData.ToArray()));  This is creating Like "Set the source image has some invalid arguments "... Would you please get rid of this.?

Comment: I don't know how your byte[] is stored... In my case, images have been stored using a similar conversion.

Comment: I have edited the Question in which I told at last that how I convert my image to byte array,, and how to re convert that..please have a look at this now

Comment: the _img1_  you set as _pro_pic_ source is the object you want as binding source for your `Image`

Comment: work_pic  source ,,,,,,I want binding for my image...that is       in my xaml code.   img1 is another control,,,,   img1 is for single image not the list of image...that is working fine... but here I want list of images to bind the work_pic source.

Comment: You can't bind the image source to a list of images. If you mean an image for each row of your listbox, convert the row's byte[] to a `BitmapImage` (like _img1_) and set it as _work_pic_ source : Listbox and DataTemplate will do the rest of the job.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90480/discussion-between-arsal-and-xum59).

Answer (score 0):

just added bit code to database class and then bind to bitmapImage

```
 <Image  Grid.RowSpan="4" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Source="{Binding _contact.bitmapImage}" Stretch="UniformToFill" Margin="5" Width="100" Height="100" Opacity="1" />

  public byte[] Image
    {
        get
        {
            return (_imgBytes);
        }
        set
        {
            _imgBytes = value;
            CreateBitmap();
        }
    }

    private async void CreateBitmap()
    {
        var result = await dbUtils.CreateBitmap(_imgBytes);
        _bitmap = result;
    }

    [Ignore]
    public BitmapImage bitmapImage
    {
        get
        {
            return (_bitmap);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I just tried your code but in data base I'm getting error. _imgBytes  where to get these bytes. I think this method needs image bytes. and we are not giving it

Comment: _imgBytes is just internal variable like private byte[] _imgBytes;

Comment: Thanks. I got your point. I add image bytes there. But it seems that your Binding doesn't work. Like   Source="{Binding _contact.bitmapImage}"  this sentence has _contact.bitmapImage   ...  what is _contact   and   the line shows an error in windows phone.  var result = await dbUtils.CreateBitmap(_imgBytes);    dbUtils  shows error.  please resolve these too.  Thanks in Advance

Comment: CreateBitmap is just method to create bitmap from bytes[].     
 public static async Task<BitmapImage> CreateBitmap(byte[] bytes)
        {
            if (bytes == null) return (DatabaseManager.NoAvatar);
                
            BitmapImage result = new BitmapImage();
            InMemoryRandomAccessStream ras = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
            DataWriter writer = new DataWriter(ras);
            writer.WriteBytes(bytes);
            await writer.StoreAsync();
            ras.Seek(0);
            await result.SetSourceAsync(ras);
            return (result);
        }