# Captured photo has vertical stripes

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I'm capturing a photo using the `WinRT` Mediacapture class, but when I take the picture it gets weird transparent stripes, it's kind of hard to explain so here's some pictures:

**Before capturing picture (Previewing)**

[image: Before capturing picture (Previewing)]

**After taking picture**

[image: After taking picture]

I have seen other people with kind of the same problem around here (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23709547/captured-photo-with-stripes), but the solutions to them didn't seem to work for me. (either no result, or the photo got messed up)

Code I use for setting the resolution:

```
System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<VideoEncodingProperties> available_resolutions = captureManager.VideoDeviceController.GetAvailableMediaStreamProperties(MediaStreamType.Photo).Select(x => x as VideoEncodingProperties);

foreach (VideoEncodingProperties resolution in available_resolutions)
{
     if (resolution != null && resolution.Width == 640 && resolution.Height == 480) //(resolution.Width==1920 && resolution.Height==1080) //resolution.Width==640 && resolution.Height==480)
     {
           await captureManager.VideoDeviceController.SetMediaStreamPropertiesAsync(MediaStreamType.Photo, resolution);
     }
}
```

Code I'm using for taking the photo:

```
private async Task<BitmapImage> ByteArrayToBitmapImage(byte[] byteArray)
    {
        var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();

        using (var stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
        {
            await stream.WriteAsync(byteArray.AsBuffer());
            stream.Seek(0);

            await bitmapImage.SetSourceAsync(stream);

            await stream.FlushAsync();
        }

        return bitmapImage;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Relayed Execute method for TakePictureCommand.
    /// </summary>
    async void ExecuteTakePicture()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Started making picture");
        DateTime starttime = DateTime.Now;

        ImageEncodingProperties format = ImageEncodingProperties.CreateJpeg();

        using (var imageStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
        {
            await captureManager.CapturePhotoToStreamAsync(format, imageStream);

            //Compresses the image if it exceedes the maximum file size
            imageStream.Seek(0);

            //Resize the image if needed
            uint maxImageWidth = 640;
            uint maxImageHeight = 480;

            if (AvatarPhoto)
            {
                maxImageHeight = 200;
                maxImageWidth = 200;

                //Create a BitmapDecoder from the stream
                BitmapDecoder resizeDecoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(imageStream);

                if (resizeDecoder.PixelWidth > maxImageWidth || resizeDecoder.PixelHeight > maxImageHeight)
                {
                    //Resize the image if it exceedes the maximum width or height
                    WriteableBitmap tempBitmap = new WriteableBitmap((int)resizeDecoder.PixelWidth, (int)resizeDecoder.PixelHeight);
                    imageStream.Seek(0);
                    await tempBitmap.SetSourceAsync(imageStream);
                    WriteableBitmap resizedImage = tempBitmap.Resize((int)maxImageWidth, (int)maxImageHeight, WriteableBitmapExtensions.Interpolation.Bilinear);
                    tempBitmap = null;

                    //Assign to imageStream the resized WriteableBitmap
                    await resizedImage.ToStream(imageStream, BitmapEncoder.JpegEncoderId);
                    resizedImage = null;
                }

                //Converts the final image into a Base64 String
                imageStream.Seek(0);
            }

            //Converts the final image into a Base64 String
            imageStream.Seek(0);

            BitmapDecoder decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(imageStream);

            PixelDataProvider pixels = await decoder.GetPixelDataAsync();
            byte[] bytes = pixels.DetachPixelData();

            //Encode image
            InMemoryRandomAccessStream encoded = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
            BitmapEncoder encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.JpegEncoderId, encoded);

            encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore, maxImageWidth, maxImageHeight, decoder.DpiX, decoder.DpiY, bytes);

            //Rotate the image based on the orientation of the camera
            if (currentOrientation == DisplayOrientations.Portrait)
            {
                encoder.BitmapTransform.Rotation = BitmapRotation.Clockwise90Degrees;
            }
            else if (currentOrientation == DisplayOrientations.LandscapeFlipped)
            {
                encoder.BitmapTransform.Rotation = BitmapRotation.Clockwise180Degrees;
            }

            if (FrontCam)
            {
                if (currentOrientation == DisplayOrientations.Portrait)
                {
                    encoder.BitmapTransform.Rotation = BitmapRotation.Clockwise270Degrees;
                }
                else if (currentOrientation == DisplayOrientations.LandscapeFlipped)
                {
                    encoder.BitmapTransform.Rotation = BitmapRotation.Clockwise180Degrees;
                }
            }

            await encoder.FlushAsync();
            encoder = null;

            //Read bytes
            byte[] outBytes = new byte[encoded.Size];
            await encoded.AsStream().ReadAsync(outBytes, 0, outBytes.Length);

            encoded.Dispose();
            encoded = null;

            //Create Base64
            image = await ByteArrayToBitmapImage(outBytes);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Pixel width: " + image.PixelWidth + " height: " + image.PixelHeight);
            base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(outBytes);

            Array.Clear(outBytes, 0, outBytes.Length);
            await imageStream.FlushAsync();
            imageStream.Dispose();
        }

        DateTime endtime = DateTime.Now;
        TimeSpan span = (endtime - starttime);

        //Kind of a hacky way to prevent high RAM usage and even crashing, remove when overal RAM usage has been lowered
        GC.Collect();

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Making the picture took: " + span.Seconds + " seconds");

        if (image != null)
        {
            RaisePropertyChanged("CapturedImage");

            //Tell both UsePictureCommand and ResetCommand that the situation has changed.
            ((RelayedCommand)UsePictureCommand).RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
            ((RelayedCommand)ResetCommand).RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        }
        else
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Imagestream is not valid");
        }
    }
```

If there is any more information needed feel free to comment, I will try to put it out as fast as possible, thanks for reading.

Comment: Have you tried to check (debug) available resolutions and choose the maximum one?

Comment: What's the resolution of your device? You're resizing the image. The camera is being shown full screen regardless of resolution. Also, where's the XAML for how the result is displayed?

Comment: @Romasz When choosing the highest resolution (by not setting it at all), it [turns into this](http://i.imgur.com/Sfi2FDq.png)

Comment: @WiredPrairie The screen resolution is 480x800, or did you mean the camera resolution (which can be multiple sizes ranging from 640x480 to 2592x1456). 

The XAML I use for displaying the image is '<Image Source="{Binding CapturedImage}"/>'


CapturedImage gives back variable 'image', which we set near the end of ExecuteTakePicture.

Comment: I did mean the screen resolution. Are you sure the image isn't just being resized to best fit the screen (as the dimensions of the image don't match the device dimensions).

Comment: @WiredPrairie I'm pretty sure it isn't a displaying issue, because when I decode the base64 string I also get to see those weird stripes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The aspect ratio of the preview has to match the aspect ratio of the captured photo, or you'll get artifacts like that one in your capture (although it actually depends on the driver implementation, so it may vary from device to device).

1. Use the `MediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.GetMediaStreamProperties()` method on the `MediaStream.VideoPreview`.
2. Get the resulting `VideoEncodingProperties`, and use the Width and Height to figure out the aspect ratio.
3. Call `MediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.GetAvailableMediaStreamProperties()` on the `MediaStream.Photo`, and find out which ones have an aspect ratio that matches (I recommend using a tolerance value, something like `0.015f` might be good)
4. Out of the ones that do, choose which one better suits your needs, e.g. by paying attention to the total resolution W * H
5. Apply your selection by calling `MediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.SetMediaStreamPropertiesAsync()` on the `MediaStream.Photo` and passing the encoding properties you want.

More information in [this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/2c79525e-0cdb-4793-bfce-42c2ac4252a3/uwp-mediacapturecapturephototostreamasync-results-in-dark-bars?forum=wpdevelop#7c0add5e-a3ad-4a26-89b1-90dc11b394bf). An SDK sample is [available here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CameraResolution).

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but this indeed seemed to fix my problem, I was setting MediaStream.Photo, but not MediaStream.VideoPreview.